# Creating a new texture from several textures SDL-2

Tags: textures, render, render-to-texture, sdl-2

I have several textures that will be staying stationary on my screen. Rather than rendering each one individually when I render, I would like to render them all as one texture. My code so far looks like:

```
SDL_Texture* target_texture = NULL;
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, target_texture);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture1, NULL, &dst1);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture2, NULL, &dst2);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture3, NULL, &dst3);
.
.
.
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
SDL_RendererPresent(renderer);
// Here the screen displays as I want
SDL_Delay(2000);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, target_texture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RendererPresent(renderer);
// Here the screen is black as though target_texture is still NULL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create your target_texture, currently it's always NULL. Replace your first line for:

```
target_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, target_width, target_height);
```